# Set priority fee for gas in a web3 transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently using the following method to interact with my contract and send a transaction:

```
 contract.methods.myMethod(amount).send({
    from: address,
    to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    value: String(totalCost),
   });
```

I did notice the .send does take the following parameters:

gasPrice - String (optional): The gas price in wei to use for this transaction.
gas - Number (optional): The maximum gas provided for this transaction (gas limit).

However, i dont see any parameter to adjust the priority fee. Is there any way to pass this trough when making a transaction this way?

Im firing the transaction from a nodejs app and is for personal use only, so i have set a private key to avoid having to sign etc. But the only thing im missing now is to set a pre-defined priority fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another post over at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/

> Miners will Prioritize the transactions with a higher gas price not a
> gas value (how much gas are you providing to be used to execute your
> transaction). the miners set a gasprice(the gas price you are willing
> to pay in ether for each unit of gas) whiting the network if you send
> a transaction with a price below your transaction will not be
> proceeded otherwise more you raise your gas price more you Prioritize
> your transaction. your transaction fee = consumed_gas * gas_price.
> your function consumes n gas you get refunded gas_value-n;